# Does TFS 2010 support Visual Studio 2003 and 2005 connections?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2005, compatibility, visual-studio-2003

I have been unable to locate any information on compatibility with Visual Studio 2003 or 2005. I currently have TFS 2010 working correctly with Visual Studio 2008, but we have some developers with Visual Studio 2003 and 2005 instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Kinda"

You'll need to install a Forward Compatibility Update and even then not all features of 2010 are supported.  You can find out more on the Team Foundation Server blog here: http://blogs.msdn.com/team_foundation/pages/compat-matrix-for-2010-rtm-team-foundation-server-to-team-explorer-2008-and-2005.aspx

Comment: I see the Forward Compatibilty update for VS 2005, but not for 2003. I don't even see VS 2003 listed in his compatibilty matrix. Any idea if it will function even with limited features?

Comment: JustinB: VS2003 does not integrate with any version of TFS.

Comment: JustinB: VS2003 uses MSSCCI.  There is a 2010 MSSCCI Power Tool that you can download and install.  You'll see info on it at the bottom of the link provided.

Answer (score 7):

To use VS 2003 you'll have to install the MSSCCI provider.

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bce06506-be38-47a1-9f29-d3937d3d88d6